# Bluetooth disconnects after a small period of time

Tags: android, bluetooth

I wrote an app that connects to a JY-MCU module, controlled by PIC, for the purpose of sending commands and diagnostics. I wrote it using the Bluetooth Chat example, and it worked fine. So I wrote the app half an year ago, and a couple of days ago I had to use it again. I have Huawei G510 phone, and the problem is that the connection dies after about 1 minute.

I have tried other programs like Bluetooth SPP - same problem, connection drops after a small period of time. The problem is not in the JY-MCU - it works perfectly fine connected to PC, and to another Android phone (V. 2.3.6). Which leaves the problem with the Huawei G510 device. The only BT options on the phone are on/off and pairing.

What could be causing that problem?

Thanks

Comment: Did you make any progress with this? Just hit the same problem .. May try a custom ROM tomorrow if I'm feeling brave ...

Comment: Yes, sorry for the late response. What I did is just made a thread in the phone that sends keepalives to the BT adapter every 10 seconds. It was an easy fix, but did the job.